# Prevent useState from multiplying eventListeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create some sort of typing test, making letters be removed from a string if they have been typed correctly. My initial approach was to use a state to save the words in, and if the correct key has been pressed, remove the first letter from the string. However, this results in a lot of bugs, such as that after around 20 correct keys, the function starts to remove multiple characters from the string and when pressed on some keys, the string even starts building itself back, pressing on 'e' and 'r' in my case. It is not an infinite render, so I'm not sure why. I think what is happening is that the eventlistener is multiplying, so it starts to remove multiple letters, if I'd console log the key pressed this confirms this as well. Here is the code.

```js
    const [words, setWords] = useState("a lot of words are put here")
    const removeLetter = (e) => {
        if (e.key === words[0]) {
            setWords((letters) => letters.substring(1));
    }
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {removeLetter(e)})
```

Comment: you can either add the listener once in a useEffect, or attach it as a React event to the relevant container.

Comment: @piclhard I have tried this, if I use it as a componentdidmount, the eventlistener will only work once, until the rerender from the state. If I make it respond on the change, the same thing will happen as the problem I have right now.

Comment: I have solved it by removing the function in the eventlistener as well as a UseEffect. I have  tried UseEffect before asking, but not removing the function, thank you guys anyways!

Comment: Glad you got it working. It looks like you were encountering a closure over the initial state (the listener was firing, but always looking for the first letter of the first initial word)